# Converting EPOCH UNIX time format using addToTime in Power Automate

Tags: json, unix-timestamp, powerapps, epoch, power-automate

I'm using power automate flow to query the Dynatrace REST API, which returns JSON formatted output.

`startTime` is returned in EPOCH UNIX time format and I'm using this expression to convert it into a human readable format:

```
addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', outputs('Compose'), 'Second')
```

The above expression converts 1638860388929 to 1912-06-02T12:57:37.0000000Z, whereas it should actually be Tuesday, 7 December 2021 06:59:48.929.

Why is my expression giving the incorrect output?

Answer (score 0):

I found half of your answer in [this article](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Got-a-recipe-for-converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-utc-date/m-p/138599#M13732).

Their answer says to use `addseconds('1970-1-1', Div(timestamp,1000) , 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

This worked for me however remember this is UTC time so if you're going to convert that to the UTC date and time that works for you you're going to need to use the following

`convertFromUtc(concat(addseconds('1970-1-1', Div(***YOUR TIME HERE***,1000) , 'o'),'Z'),'Pacific Standard Time','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')`

You'll add your time where I specified and change your time zone to fit whichever works for you ([find a list of specifiers here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)).

Note: I needed to add a "Z" to the time to make it comply with the convertFromUTC function.